# Grant acess to folder application pool (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have app on Azure App services

In project `wwwroot` I have uploads folder.

I need to grant it full control read permission

I connect to website using IIS Manager

Here is screen

[image]

And have application pool settings

[image]

But I don't understand how I can give permissions to folder

Help me please

**UPDATE**

I go to this folders and check permissions

Full control is on

[image]

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but can't you give appropriate permission to that folder outside of IIS simply by going to the properties of the folder and granting access to the same account that Application Pool Identity relates to?

Comment: you talk about grant permissions to folder in windows?@DanielShillcock

Comment: Correct. I assume that you're trying to access the folder server side to read contents of folder. To do that, grant sufficient privilege for the user accessing the folder; in this case, whatever the app pool identity is.

Comment: Hm. I open Security and this folder has all permissions

http://imgur.com/a/tu51N @DanielShillcock

Comment: That folder related to a folder inside `wwwroot`? Is your application pool identity using j.suhomlin? I am sure some research will yield lots of results relating to accessing folder permissions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141408/discussion-between-eugene-and-daniel-shillcock).

Comment: In folder security tab add IIS_IUSRS as a user and give the permission. And change NETWORK SERVICE permissions too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit permissions again and try to add Machine\Users and IUSRS. 
Verify Authentication configuration is the desired for your site (For example Anonimous Auth + Edit -> AppPoolIdentity)